# lambda@edge logs and invocation counts are not showing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have created the cloud front distribution and attached the lambda with the trigger

```
`Event type: viewer-requestPath pattern: something/index.html`

 Event type: origin-requestPath pattern: something/index.html
```

When i hit the endpoint it's redirecting to the page where i want to redirect, according to my lambda.

but i was not able to see my lambda logs in any region.

it was not showing the invocation count also.

Did anyone faced this issue ??

Here is my lambda code

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    /*
     * Generate HTTP redirect response with 302 status code and Location header.
     */
    console.log('event',event);
    const response = {
        status: '302',
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers: {
            location: [{
                key: 'Location',
                value: 'http://<domainname>/something/root.html',
            }],
        },
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your function like this:

```
const response = {
        status: '302',
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers: {
            location: [{
                key: 'Location',
                value: 'http://<domainname>/something/root.html',
            }],
            'x-lae-region': [ { key: 'x-lae-region', value: process.env.AWS_REGION } ],
        },
    };
```

What this does is capture the region where your lambda function is running -- it will show us-east-1 during test, but show an accurate value once deployed.

Responses captured by your browser, curl, etc., will now include `x-lae-region: some-aws-region` to indicate the region linked to the edge where your specific requests are being handled.  Check the logs for that specific region -- you should see logs and invocations there.

Also note that for an Origin Request (but not Viewer Request) trigger, CloudFront caches the response generated by Lambda, so the function will only be invoked when there is a cache miss.  If CloudFront has cached the response, the trigger will not fire -- the cached response is served without contacting the origin.  If you make this function live and you don't see the change in the responses, then you are almost certainly looking at cached responses, and will want to do an invalidation.

Comment: Thanks for the response . i did the change in the lambda code . still i am not getting the logs .i am not finding the loggroups / lambda in any other region other than Virginia . i created the new cache behavior and tested its still the same .

Comment: What region do you see in the response headers when you access your site?

Comment: Thank you so much. It works i can see the logs but not the metrics lambda count remains 0.

Comment: Great... but *which region* do you see in the response headers?

Comment: i am seeing in Mumbai region

Comment: Thank you.  You might consider using [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html) to change the geographic area that your connection appears to be coming from so that you can see how other regions behave, to help determine whether the issue is present in other regions as well.

Comment: Awesome Thanks for the great info, i will try that out :)

Answer (score 2):

I came across a very similar issue and it threw me off for several hours. For Lambda@Edge the data on the Lambda metrics in the AWS console tab does not seem to be accurate for invocations and logs.  At least they are not complete.

I only saw metrics on this tab related to my "test" event invocations that originated from the console. I was able to find my full invocation metrics in CloudWatch in the same region that my Lambda was deployed to under the name us-east-1.LambdaName-EdgeLambda-14DOC7T1Y1SGR and the test invocations were listed under a similar metric minus the region. The logs were also named after the region the Lambda was deployed to. For example, /aws/lambda/us-east-1.LambdaName-EdgeLambda-14DOC7T1Y1SGR. My test logs were listed in a separate log group without the region in the name.